# Error with this message : Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'lon' not found

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, plot

I am using a csv data table to plot soil properties. I have lat and long for the location of the soil samples. When I run the `mydata <- subset(data, !is.na(lon) & !is.na(lat))` it gives me an error code. I tried using `long` and it says the same thing.

> Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'lon' not found

```r
data <- read.csv("C:Users/Derri/Desktop/RandomForest/0-10cm-new coordinates.csv", 
                 sep=";", header = TRUE)
dim(data)
head(data)
mydata <- subset(data, !is.na(lon) & !is.na(lat))
dim(mydata)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your columns are named correctly?
Try using colnames() to check.
Below you can see that, with a data.frame I generated, your code works.

```
> data <- data.frame(
+   lat = c(1:3,NA),
+   lon = c(NA,3:1)
+ )
> 
> dim(data)
[1] 4 2
> head(data)
  lat lon
1   1  NA
2   2   3
3   3   2
4  NA   1
> mydata <- subset(data, !is.na(lon) & !is.na(lat))
> dim(mydata)
[1] 2 2
```